# How to request a certificate from client installed on his computer

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I need to request from client a certificate installed on his computer. There is a site which realized this

[image: there user press the custom link and browser request for certificate]

.  I don't need it for page I need this certificate request for custom link which will be on the page.